# Change chromdriver for Rselenium

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Rselenium and I want to use it to scrape data from a website. When trying to establish a connection I get the error that my chrome driver is not compatible with my current browser version, here is the code and the error I got so far

```
library(RSelenium)
library(RCurl)

driver <- rsDriver()
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$open()

> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97
Current browser version is 96.0.4664.45 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

The error report is very long, but I think the essence of the error is described in the first sentence; my chromedriver and current version of chrome are not compatible.

So I did some research, since I don't know what a chrome driver is. I found out I can download older versions of chrome driver. I searched the 96.0.4664.45 version since my browser is that version (it seems there is only a 32 bit version, which I thought was odd but its the only one for windows so I downloaded that one).

After I downloaded the chromedriver.exe, I moved it to a specific folder and I added that folder to my system path as I read online this is what I have to do in order for R to recognize. Then, I used the cmd prompt to execute the chrome driver, which seems to work;

[image]

Then when I start up R and retry, I still got the same error, so it seems I am still doing something wrong. Do I need to 'overide' the chromedriver 97? And why do I even have a version 97 when my browser is a 96? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use a dedicated instances of the driver and the browser to simplify the crucial matching. You can just spin up a standalone version of selenium using [docker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) and then connect RSelenium to that container. Your local chrome version will change every couple of days anyways. Your local approch requires manual syncing of the driver and the chrome...

Comment: @danlooo Thank you for the tip, how would I do that using Rstudio?

Comment: Install [Docker desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) and follow instructions at the [Rselenium vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) in the docker section. Docker is a general purpose tool to put software in isolated boxes, it is not specific to R.

Comment: @danlooo Thanks I will try it out

Comment: This is a well known problem with RSelenium, e.g. see https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/221 from two years ago.  Solutions have been offered (including in that thread), but RSelenium isn't really being maintained.

Comment: Thank you @danlooo it works very well :)